# The name 'zipfile' does not exist in the current context

Tags: c#, ssis, zip

I have an SSIS project that I can run as is, but when I try to edit it, I get an error:

> The name 'zipfile' does not exist in the current context

Without editing, it works fine.

The code that's producing the error:

```
public void Main()
{
    // TODO: Add your code here
    string moduleName = Dts.Variables["User::ModuleName"].Value.ToString();
    string s = Dts.Variables["User::ZipFileLocation"].Value.ToString().TrimEnd('\\') + "\\" + moduleName + "\\" + moduleName + "_" + DateTime.Now.ToString("ddMMyyyy");

    // TODO: Add your code here
    string startPath = s;
    string zipPath = s + ".zip";

    try
    {
        File.Delete(zipPath);
        ZipFile.CreateFromDirectory(startPath, zipPath);
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
    }

    Dts.TaskResult = (int)ScriptResults.Success;
}
```

How can I solve this?

Comment: You probably only referenced System.IO.Compression, strangely enough you need to reference System.IO.Compression.FileSystem too

Comment: @NilsO This was the issue for me. Not sure why we have to add a separate reference for this, but nonetheless fixed the issue on my end.

Comment: @Chad it's because the Zipfile class is in the System.IO.Compression.FileSystem assembly while it's in the System.IO.Compression namespace.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Make sure you are using .NET version 4.5. Reference the Compression DLL - here is the path:

`C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\.NETFramework\v4.5\System.IO.Compression.FileSystem.dll`

Reference it in the class by adding `using System.IO.Compression.FileSystem`. If the class is inherited from another class, make sure to reference it in the parent class too. (This is what I have to do to make it compile)

Comment: you don't need dlls just use https://stackoverflow.com/a/43196451/631527 below

Answer (score 6):

To use the `ZipFile` class, you must add a reference to the `System.IO.Compression.FileSystem` assembly in your project; otherwise, you'll get the following error message when trying to compile:

> The name 'ZipFile' does not exist in the current context.

For more information on how to add a reference to your project in Visual Studio, see [How to: Add or remove references by using the Reference Manager](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/ide/how-to-add-or-remove-references-by-using-the-reference-manager?view=vs-2017).

Answer (score 3):

I found that the `ZipFile` class would not cooperate only using `System.IO.Compression`, it asked to see a **Reference** to `System.IO.Compression.FileSystem`.

If you're using Visual Basic, adding a reference is fairly easy. In the solution explorer, one of the tabs under the project is called *References*. Right click there and select *Add Reference*. Scroll down a bit an check the checkbox next to `System.IO.Compression.FileSystem`. Once you click *OK*, you shouldn't even need to explicitly reference `System.IO.Compression.FileSystem` in your code!

Good luck (:

Answer (score 1):

**Just for Update: -**

**With .Net 4.6.1 version**

Adding reference to `System.IO.Compression.FileSystem` and `using System.IO.Compression` is enough.

`using System.IO.Compression.FileSystem` is giving below error.

[image: Reference error]

Comment: Yeah I see the same thing.